# не видит poplib,установил pip, и там же не получается установить poplib и imaplib,вот код в IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2 x64

Tags: python

server = poplib.POP3_SSL(SERVER)

server.user(USER)
server.pass_(PASSWORD)

resp, items, octets = server.list()

numMessages = len(items)

Answer (score 0):

В начале ВСЕГДА нужно импортировать нужные Вам модули. Добавьте это в начало вашего кода.

```
import poplib
```

[Источник](https://docs.python.org/3/library/poplib.html)